# I´m unable to map elements of an array

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Im trying to receive the data from my api into the charts at my website.
Im stuck trying to fill my charts with the data, I have the code for filling the charts but when I map the JSON data and try to split the data into Date and temperature to put it in the chart it just does not work.

This is the code:

```
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:8090/api/grafico/datos/temperatura/medicionAire/2059";
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
       //console.log(data);
        
        var dateG = data.map(function(elem) {
            return elem.fecha;
        });
        var temperatureG = data.map(function(elem) {
            return elem.temperatura;
        });

    }
}
```

I tried debuging it and it look like it does not recognize "fecha" or "temperatura" inside the array eventhough "elem" has the array in it:
As you can see in this image, "elem" has the array in it, but "elem.fecha" is undefined and I dont know why. It should return me an array with only "fecha" of each line.

[image]

Log output of data:

```
[Array(4)]
0: Array(4)
0: {fecha: '2021-09-03T13:15:41.943Z', temperatura: 22.33}
1: {fecha: '2021-09-03T13:15:41.230Z', temperatura: 22.33}
2: {fecha: '2021-09-03T13:15:04.243Z', temperatura: 22.33}
3: {fecha: '2021-09-03T13:14:06.923Z', temperatura: 16.56}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: It seems to me `elem` contains an array of objects which then contain the fields you want to access... try `return elem[0].fecha` to see whether my theory is correct. Maybe you can also post the log output of "data" ? It would give a better idea of what the data you work with looks like

Comment: @N4ppeL oh yeah, 'return elem[0].fecha' gives me the 1st element of it, you are right. I guess, my solution is to for() through it and save it in a new array, so i can send it to my charts. Or maybe transform the array of objects into a readable format? 1st solution looks easier

Comment: You can just map a 2nd time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you were to modify you code into something like so:

```
    var dateG = data.map(function(elem) {
        return elem.map(function(innerElem) {
            return innerElem.fecha
        });
    });
```

You would end up with `dateG` as 2D array of fetcha values.

Comment: Thanks mate, that worked!! For anyone using this later there is some syntax error, but it works!

Comment: the triple n in inner ? sorry ^^ if you catch anything feel free to edit my answer :D

Comment: yeah the triple n and a bracket didnt know I could edit answers hehe. thanks for your time mate